# a function is approximated by a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $g$ be a positive function on $(0,1)$ such that $g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to 0$.

Then, there exists a convex function $h$ on $(0,1)$ such that $h\leq g$ and $h(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to 0$.

We can find an example easily,such as $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Here, in fact, $g$ itself is a convex function, but how about a concrete construction of $h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ denote the "epigraph" of $g$, i.e., the set of points of the form $(x,y)$, $y\ge g(x), x\in (0,1)$. Let $C$ denote the closed convex hull of $E$ in the strip $0<x<1$. Then clearly, $C$ has the form
$$
\{(x,y): y\ge h(x)\} 
$$
where $h(x)$ is convex and $h\le g$. I claim that $h$ is the required function. Indeed, if $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)=c<\infty$, then by convexity and the hypothesis, there exists a $\epsilon>0$ so that for all $x\in (0,\epsilon)$, $h(x)$ is bounded above by a linear function $\ell(x)$ with $\ell(0)\ge c$, while $g(x)\ge \ell(0)+1$ for all $x\in (0,\epsilon)$.

Edit: The function $\ell$ then satisfies the property that its slope is larger than the left derivative $h'_-(\epsilon)$.

Therefore, by considering the graph of $\ell$ we see that $C$ is not the losed convex hull of $E$ (as you can cut off a piece of it by the graph of $\ell$ and still obtain a closed convex set containing $E$).

Edit: Few more details: Consider the  set $C'$ which is the union of the epigraph of $\ell(x)$ on $(0,\epsilon)$ and of the epigraph of $h(x)$ on $(\epsilon,1)$. The slope property mentioned above ensures that $C'$ is still convex. By construction $C'$ contains $E$ and is strictly smaller than $C$. Contradiction.  qed

Comment: @littleO Yes, of course, I just forgot the name. I will correct this. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you require the linearity of $l$?Just to preserve the convexity of $h$?And the graph of $l$ is $G(l)=\{(x,y):y=l(x)\geq h(x),l(0)\geq c\}$,while there is still some $x\in (0,1)$ such that $E\subset G(l)$,but what's the section of $G(l)$ satisfing your conclusion?Is it $\{(x,y):y\geq c+1\}$?

Comment: @mathon: Yes, linearity is used to ensure convexity. For the rest, I will add more details to the argument.